# How to call the index value of the data frame as an arg in apply function with python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `df` with following format:

```
        text
0       hi john
1       how are you
2       666
3       so crazy
...
```

And I wish to write each row one by one in a different file with the index number as the file name. For instance, `'hi john'` should be written to `0.txt`

Given the function:

```
def writeText(text, index):
    with open(str(number)+'.txt', 'w+') as f:
        f.write(text)
```

Now I need to `apply` it to `df`:

```
df.apply(writeText, args=(??????, ))
```

What args should I pass to the function so that the index number can be used? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first convert `text` column to [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) and then use [`numpy.ndarray.tofile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) in loop for writing data:

```
print df

          text
0      hi john
1  how are you
2          666
3     so crazy

for row in df.text.reset_index().values:
    print row
    row[1:].tofile(str(row[0])+'.txt', sep="\t", format="%s")

    [0L 'hi john']
    [1L 'how are you']
    [2L '666']
    [3L 'so crazy']
```

Another option:

```
def writeText(df):
    for row in df.text.reset_index().values:
        with open(str(row[0])+'.txt', 'w+') as f:
            f.write(str(row[1]))

writeText(df)
```

But if you need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) `function` to `DataFrame` use [`iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html):

```
def writeText(x):
    for row in x.iteritems():
        with open(str(row[0])+'.txt', 'w+') as f:
            f.write(str(row[1]))

df.apply(writeText)
```

Comment: It's surprising that the speed is very fast even I use for loop to iterate over the rows as you said.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe the main bottleneck is writing to file. Thank you for accepting.